# Mat-Datepicker displayed date always local, never in UTC

Tags: angular, datepicker, momentjs

I'm using a **datepicker** and **momentjs** in order to send UTC dates to my server, which works 100%.  However, when I read out these UTC dates back into the date picker, it always observes my timezone (I'm EST for what it's worth) which to a user is the incorrect date selected.

**EXAMPLE:**

I select '**09/10/2019**', this goes to my database as **1567987200** or '**09/10/2019 00:00:00.000**'.

When read out, it displays '**09/09/2019**' (although the value never changes within the model and is still represented as **1567987200**).

I need to be able to not only select the value as UTC, but also display in UTC within the datepicker.  Is this possible?

**DateView.ts**

```
...
<div>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input #date="ngModel"
               matInput
               [matDatepicker]="datePicker"
               placeholder="Date"
               [(ngModel)]="model.date"
               ngClass="date-input"
               required>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker touchUi #datePicker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
...
```

**DateModule.ts**

```
...
providers: [
    { provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } }
],
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with a built in moment function.

```
moment.unix(date).utc();
```

From the documentation:

> Despite Unix timestamps being UTC-based, the `moment.unix()` function creates a
>   moment object in local mode. If you need UTC, then subsequently call
>   `.utc()`, as in: `var day = moment.unix(1318781876).utc();`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display UTC time, you can set the UTC offset to 0 like this

```
moment(1567987200).utcOffset(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```